# PYQT5 GUI App Freezing when adding bulk(100+) item to list-widget and Quiting the app

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Listwidget Declaration

```
self.fileList = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
self.fileList.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
self.fileList.currentItemChanged.connect(self.item_clicked)
```

I am Populating list items to listwidget using

```
for f in data:
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
    item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/logo.png'))
    item.setText(f)
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    self.fileList.addItem(item)
```

Where f contains bulk data

```
f=['1','2','3'................]
```

**NOTE: When element is less than 20 its working perfectly but when element count goes higher its lagging and exiting app and didn't give any log in console**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: pyqt5 app automatically quit when more elements adding to listwidget

Comment: How big is your logo.png file?

Comment: mylogo size is 2.83kb logo size is not problem even i am not setting logo still adding too much element giving issue